# plotly_POST: the plot appears in R Viewer, but not online

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to publish the plot online via these two lines of code in R:

```
library('plotly')
plot_ly(data = sampledata, x = date, y = id, type = 'bar')
plotly_POST(sampledata, filename = "Test",  world_readable=TRUE)
```

It doesn't give me any errors or warnings and says "Success! Created a new plotly here ->"

The plot appears in R Viewer, but if I go to my plotly account (or follow the link), I see a blank graph like this:

[Blank plotly bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkrRh.png)

I previously was able to publish one graph online - but I don't recall changing anything in my code.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to send the whole figure:

```
p <- plot_ly(data = sampledata, x = date, y = id, type = 'bar')
plotly_POST(p, filename = "Test",  world_readable=TRUE)
```

For a little more information on `plotly_POST` you can check out this reference: https://plot.ly/r/file-options/